# JPA query don't work with IN command and collections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have problems with with my Spring Boot backend.
I want to implement a dymnamic filter on some data.
The user should be able to do muliple types filter like
http://localhost:8082/listing/?types=offer&types=buy

With my solution below I always get the error Unknown wrap conversion requested and IndexOutOfBoundExceptions.

The Collection is never null in my tests but can be null if the user dont want to filter the types -> [offer] [offer, buy]

Because of this I added types is NULL in the query to make it dynamic and ignore this select when no types are handed over.

I already looked at stackoverflow but every suggestion i found didn't work for me.

I have a problem with he types list and how I am using it in the custom query, but I don't get it.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
fun getAllListings(
    @RequestParam(required = false) category: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) subcategory: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) seller: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) search: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) shipping: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) condition: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) types: Collection<String>?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) minPrice: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) maxPrice: String?,
): ResponseEntity<List<Listing>> {
    val listings = listingService.findAll(
        category = category,
        subcategory = subcategory,
        search = search,
        shipping = shipping,
        condition = condition,
        types = types,
        minPrice = minPrice?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: minPrice?.toInt()?.toDouble(),
        maxPrice = maxPrice?.toDoubleOrNull() ?: maxPrice?.toInt()?.toDouble()
    )
    return if (listings != null) {
        ResponseEntity.ok(listings)
    } else {
        ResponseEntity.notFound().build()
    }
}
```

Service

```
fun findAll(
    category: String?, subcategory: String?,
    search: String?, shipping: String?, condition: String?,
    types: Collection<String>?,
    minPrice: Double?, maxPrice: Double?
): List<Listing>? {
    return listingRepository.findTest(types)
}
```

Repository

```
@Query(
    "SELECT l FROM Listing l WHERE (:types IS NULL OR l.type IN :types)"
)
fun findTest(types: Collection<String>?): List<Listing>
```

Comment: could you try to rewrite `WHERE` part of query something like next one ? `WHERE ((:types IS NULL) OR (l.type IN :types))` I think it is going to solve your problem

Comment: I tried it, when I pass one paramter it works, but with two paramters it does't work

with two i get a exception: [Request processing failed: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0] with root causejava.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0

Comment: I tried your solution WHERE ((:types IS NULL) OR (l.type IN :types))
and WHERE (COALESCE(:types, NULL) = '' OR l.type IN (:types))

Comment: I have some news. With the following statement multiple filters are working
"SELECT l FROM Listing l WHERE (l.type IN :types)"
The problem is here, that when I am passing an empty Collection, what can be if users dont want to filter the type, it doesn't work

Comment: Till i found a solution I will look manually if types is null and will implement a fallback when calling the repository function -> types = types ?: listOf("offer", "buy"). The good thing is that I a have fixed types so I can code them fix in the code

Comment: I'm glad you've found your issue, but.. "every suggestion i found didn't work for me" - unless you are going to list these suggestions, your question isn't a good one for Stackoverflow as we would all make the same suggestions that you've already discounted. If you want dynamic queries, use criteria api or use different queries for very different data (a collection being empty/null is very different from one with values). One uber query for all situations is going to lead you to issues.